# Can we connect external data to k2?

Tags: k2

I am new to `K2` and have to check how similar is it to `MS Access`. So I need to know whether we connect external data from example from `SQL server` to `K2`.

Comment: well now ... nobody knows if "you" guys can do it - but the rest of the world : yes, probably.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, K2 uses [SmartObjects](https://help.k2.com/onlinetraining/bp1/default.htm#100ABZ/What-are-SmartObjects.htm%3FTocPath%3D100ABZ%253A%2520Introduction%2520to%2520K2%7CPart%25202%253A%2520Understanding%2520K2%2520Applications%2520and%2520application%2520elements%7C_____2) to connect to external data sources (like [SQL Server](http://bliblablog.net/create-k2-smartobject-from-any-sql-database/)).

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely! Connecting with many disparate repositories of data is K2's great strength.

To connect to a SQL Server, you simply have to create an instance of the SQL service broker, with the details of the server and database you want to read from. Then you can create a SmartObject for each table, view, or stored procedure within that SQL Server database that you need to interact with.

The following thread on K2 Community should get you started: http://community.k2.com/t5/K2-blackpearl/How-to-connect-K2-blackpearl-with-MS-SQL-R2/td-p/53993

Answer (score 0):

K2 is not similar to Access since it is larger platform which meets enterprise workflow automation needs whereas Access would rather allow you to build department level apps with little flexibility - so comparison is incorrect neither from feature set nor from product positioning or pricing point of views.

K2 has 3 major pillars tightly integrated with each other:

**Workflow Engine** (manages execution of steps defined for process you automating)

**SmartForms** (allow to build you web UI to your apps and processes)

**SmartObjects** - this abstraction layer offers you set of OOB connectors which allow you to consume or write data from variety of external LOB systems - SQL Server, Oracle, SharePoint and many more. Custom brokers can be created to connect to any other LOB system which is not covered by OOB brokers set.

So in terms of connecting to different to external data you won't have any problems and capabilities are far greater than those you may find in MS Access. Comparing those two things it is almost like compare SMB shared folder VS SharePoint Server or something like this.

Also product being marketed (and build in that way) to allow "code-less development" - it has really gentle learning curve / allows you to start quick with building your applications.